# Change Link Single Page Post

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I love use WordPress, but i have a problem here. The problem is that it is impossible for me to make the same title in the article post.

For example:

The title of my post is "Making delicious coffee" then in a single article the standard link will be like this:

```
www.blogname.com/2019/08/18/making-delicious-coffee/
```

So how do I make an additional title automatically when the single article becomes like this:

```
www.blogname.com/2019/08/18/how-to-making-delicious-coffee/
```

Can be seen, on the second link there is an additional word "How To". So how and what is the name of the technique to add the word?

Thanks before,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) Add this rewrite at the end of you function.php

```
function add_rewrite_rules( $wp_rewrite )
{
    $new_rules = array(
        'how-to-(.+?)/?$' => 'index.php?post_type=post&name='. $wp_rewrite->preg_index(1),
    );
    $wp_rewrite->rules = $new_rules + $wp_rewrite->rules;
}
add_action('generate_rewrite_rules', 'add_rewrite_rules'); 

function change_blog_links($post_link, $id=0){
    $post = get_post($id);
    if( is_object($post) && $post->post_type == 'post'){
        return home_url('/how-to-'. $post->post_name.'/');
    }
    return $post_link;
}
add_filter('post_link', 'change_blog_links', 1, 3);
```

2) Go to Settings > Permalinks and click Save Changes.

Comment: I understand that. But how do I do it automatically. I don't have to edit the permalink on the page when we are about to create a new post.

Answer (score 0):

You can add same titles for 2 posts, but the URL should be different. If you are not configured the URL, the WordPress will automatically changes the URL structure like:

```
sitename/single-post
sitename/single-post2
```

Also you should be concerned about duplication of meta titles.